# Export excel from sharepoint list without symbol # in lookup

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, export-to-excel, sharepoint-online

When exporting the data from the Sharepoint list, columns of Lookup type are added a "#" in front of the original data. Is there any solution to remove that symbol?

Answer (score 0):

It is by default. There is no way to remove "#" in front of the original values.

As a workaround, you can create a new Single of Line text column called Text01 in my sample, and use SharePoint Designer workflow to set its value to the values of the Lookup column like the below:
[image]

After that, go to the list settings, and modify the view and uncheck the lookup column under **Columns** section.

After the above, when you export the list using "Export to Excel", the result will be like:
[image]